# Conditional Operator in asp.net repeater databinding

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, repeater

I have this in asp.net source page (while binding repeater with data

```
 <%#Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsTax")) ? "Yes": "No Tax"%>
```

I Need the following two in place of Yes. How can i?

```
  <%#Eval("TaxAmount")%>
<%#Eval("TaxGroup")%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this....

```
<%#Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsTax")) ? (Eval("TaxAmount").ToString()+" " 
+Eval("TaxGroup").ToString()): "No Tax"%>
```